# Return value optimization of values unpacked from std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, return-value-optimization

Are there any compilers capable of performing return value optimization on multiple values returned from a function through std::tuple? To be clear, in the following code, are there any compilers capable of avoiding unnecessary copies?

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::list<float> b;
std::tie(a,b) = myFunctionThatReturnsAVectorAndList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not worth worrying anymore. If the compiler cannot perform RVO, [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/) will kick in.